# Getting text from inside HTML tag without knowing all attributes

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm trying to crawl all the repository names found in the docker hub via this link: https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=*&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=1&pullCount=0&starCount=0

The HTML tag I'm interested in is:

```
<div class="RepositoryListItem__repoName___3iIWs" data-reactid=".s0zyncta0w.1.2.1.0.0.$4lexnz/overtime.0.0.1.0">4lexnz/overtime</div>
```

where the data-reactid is always different for each repository.

I'm using Bash and would like to grep the text between the div tag for each div that contains class="RepositoryListItem__repoName___3iIWs". Can someone please help me construct a regexp and command chain to do that in bash?

So far I have:

```
content=$(curl -L 'https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=*&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&pullCount=0&starCount=0')
echo $content | grep -oP '(?<=<div class="RepositoryListItem__repoName___3iIWs").*?(?= </div>)'
```

but this doesnt return anything at all. The value of $content is correct so it's the last grep that's not doing what I want. Can someone help please? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use something like:

```
content=$(curl -L 'https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=*&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&pullCount=0&starCount=0')
echo $content | grep -oP '<div class="RepositoryListItem__repoName___3iIWs"\s(.)+?>(\K.+?)(?=<\/div>)'
```

It seems working for me, in this way you can extract a group containing exactly the text inside the `<div >` and `</div>`.

Please note that I'm quite new in using RegEx with grep, so there could be something clever, but this can do what you are looking for.
The `\K` flag remove all matching before it, and with `(?=)` I remove the `</div>` part from the match.

Comment: Great! I added some extra info in case you want to make it better! ;)